# What options are there for passport delivery to a Syrian national in the USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, mail, syrian-citizens

A Syrian national wants to leave the USA and return to her home country ASAP. Therefore, she needs to receive her passport, which is currently with relatives in Germany.

• Is it, in general, legally admissible (from a US perspective) to mail a foreign passport to the States?

• What German/US enterprises offer such a service?

• Any hint whether there will be considerable screening delays at Customs?

• If everything else fails, could a private courier (German friend) get into trouble when entering the US to deliver the passport?

The staff from several mail enterprises unfortunately were unable to point to clear advice. Also partial answers are highly welcome.

Comment: Seeing as the US delivers passports to its own citizens by mail, I can't imagine why it would have a problem with anyone else mailing passports around.  They're not illegal to possess and they don't have any market value, so I can't imagine why customs would care either.  Of course, it's hard to prove a negative.

Answer (score 5):

DHL does that. I've shipped a passport via DHL (which happens to be a German company) overseas and back.